# Database Insertion error due to query

Tags: java, database

I have a new database.I want to insert manual values and picking table name from a database. But it shows an error.The following code i use.My row values are first one is a `String` and following are Integers(here=fcltyname is the only `String`)

```
 connection = (Connection) dbSource.getConnection();
        String qry = "SELECT studentName From batcha "; 
        System.out.println(fcltyName);

        stmt = (PreparedStatement)  connection.prepareStatement(qry);
            rs =  stmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {

                String check=new String(rs.getString(("studentName")));
                String student = check.replaceAll("\\s","");

                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL_table, USER, PASS);

                String sql1 = "INSERT IGNORE INTO "+student+" (fcltyName,CommunicationOral,Communicationwritten,Leadership,AnalyticalAbilities,Interpersonalskills,DecisionMakingSkills,SelfConfidence,Creativity,Punctualityregularity,GeneralAwareness,Commitment,HardWork)VALUES("+fcltyName+",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)"; 

                newStmt=(PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(sql1); 

            newStmt.executeUpdate(sql1); 

            newStmt.close();
```

Error

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)' at line 1
```

Comment: Why can't you use the same connection for insert query ?

Comment: your query goes to server wrong missing **(** operator

Comment: You have to wrap `fcltyName` with simple quotes: VALUES('"+fcltyName+"'...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this once

'

```
    try {
        String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER"+ "fcltyName,CommunicationOral,Communicationwritten,Leadership,AnalyticalAbilities,Interpersonalskills,DecisionMakingSkills,SelfConfidence,Creativity,Punctualityregularity,GeneralAwareness,Commitment,HardWork) VALUES"+ "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

        preparedStatement.setStringt(1, fcltyName);
        preparedStatement.setInt(2, 0);
        preparedStatement.setInt(3, 0);
        preparedStatement.setInt(4,0);
        preparedStatement.setInt(5, 0);
        preparedStatement.setInt(6, 0);
        preparedStatement.setInt(7,0);
        preparedStatement.setInt(8, 0);
        preparedStatement.setInt(9, 0);
        preparedStatement.setInt(10,0);
        preparedStatement.setInt(11, 0);
        preparedStatement.setInt(12, 0);
        preparedStatement.setInt(13,0);

        // execute insert SQL stetement
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();}'
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
String sql1 = "INSERT IGNORE INTO "+student+" (fcltyName,CommunicationOral,Communicationwritten,Leadership,AnalyticalAbilities,Interpersonalskills,DecisionMakingSkills,SelfConfidence,Creativity,Punctualityregularity,GeneralAwareness,Commitment,HardWork)VALUES('"+fcltyName+"',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)";
```

Comment: I would not recommend inserting values like this. It is prone to sql injection and the queries cannot be cached.

Answer (score 1):

I think fcltyName is a varchar type so you need to insert it within 'fcltyName'

```
String sql1 = "INSERT IGNORE INTO "+student+" (fcltyName,CommunicationOral,Communicationwritten,Leadership,AnalyticalAbilities,Interpersonalskills,DecisionMakingSkills,SelfConfidence,Creativity,Punctualityregularity,GeneralAwareness,Commitment,HardWork)VALUES("+"'"+fcltyName+"'"+",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)";
```

Comment: @DeepthiDipin string in java but varchar in sql

Comment: @DeepthiDipin as suresh has said,try to use preparedstatement always

Answer (score 0):

Do not insert values directly in the query, use a preparedstatment and feed the values as arguments.

See http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/ for an example